# View Security Server and Direct Connection

Tags: firewall, rdp

I have a Security Server for my connections from the Internet. This works fine, accept when I enable "Direct Connection to the desktop". I found the following statement on this:

If you bypass the secure connection, the client must establish a direct RDP communication to the desktop virtual machine over RDP (port 3389).

Does this mean I have to open 3389 (RDP) to the Internet if I want to use Direct Connections?

If I disable Direct Connections to get my Security Server working, I have to disable it on my Connection Server. It's my understanding that this means that if I reboot my Connection Server, all the View clients get disconnected. Is there a way I can disable "Direct Connections" for the Security Server, while enabling it for access from the LAN?

Tia.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you must defirewall the RDP port.